# css margin/aligning issue

Tags: html, css

I'll try to explain this as best as I can ;)
Basically, I have a sidebar `<div id="sidebar"></div>` which is floated to the leftside and has fixed position. I planned to have another div just after it that will contain the content, but the problem is that, because sidebar has fixed position the div that I expect to be after it (to the right side) is appearing behind sidebar. This is an issue, because I need to use `margin-left: 310px` (310px is a width of sidebar) to make another div appear after the sidebar, so instead of occupying 100% width left on the page without a sidebar's 310px it occupies full page and causes align problems.

It's hard to explain, but if you visit my page http://freshbeer.lv/development/en/ you can see white div, it has `margin-left: 310px;` and `width: 100%;` inside it there is a grey div with `width:700px;` and `margin: 0 auto;`. I expect grey div to be aligned in the middle between 2 images at the background, but as white div is occupying more space than needed it doesn't happen. Could anyone suggest a solution please?

Comment: Have you tried adding the pictures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but in `#container` you can either remove `width: 100%` or change it to `width: auto`.

The problem is that it is getting the width of the parent container (which if you go far enough back is taking the width of your browser window) and then adding the margin. So it is 100% + 310px. Hence the reason it is 310px wider than your browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  First, make sure that your side bar is first in your script.  Then, do not set the width of your main section.  Instead, just say `display:block`.  So something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:310px; float:left; background:#dddddd; height:500px;"></div>
<div style="margin-left:310px; display:block; background:#ff0000; height:500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example, the top div is your side bar, and the second your main body section.  I just added the heights so I could see the columns during testing.